# Does Oracle have an equivalent to Postgres' text_pattern_ops opclass?

Tags: oracle, postgresql

In postgres I can make an index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX name_last_first_upper_ix
ON name(upper(last::text) text_pattern_ops, upper(first::text) text_pattern_ops);
```

`text_pattern_ops` makes the index usable for both equality (`upper(last) = 'FOO' AND upper(first) = 'CHEESE'`) and for trailing wildcard (`upper(last) LIKE 'BAR%' AND upper(first) LIKE 'CHEE%`) searches.

Is there an equivalent concept in Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Oracle does not such an Option because it's not necessary there.

Just create the index:

```
CREATE INDEX name_last_first_upper_ix
   ON name(upper(last), upper(first));
```

That index will be used if your query contains the same expression, e.g. `where upper(last) = 'FOO'` or `where upper(last) like 'FOO%'`

Comment: Edited my question to have the accurate and specific example.